# How to connect magento 2.3.5-p2 with magento PWA studio 8

Tags: magento2, progressive-web-apps, magento-2.3

I need connect Magento 2.3.5-p2 with Magento PWA studio 8. When I try to run PWA I get the error:

`Error: Cannot query field "availableStores" on type "Query". (... 1 errors total) at fetch.then.catch.then.json (/home/michal/magento2/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:33:23) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`.

I know these versions are incompatible, but maybe someone had to do it as well and has some suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: If you know two things are not compatible why are you trying to use them together? Voting to close as no repro (unlikely to be helpful to future readers).

Answer (score 0):

@Michal i had similar issue with my magento store and in my case it was klarna payment was causing some issue.

you may easily debug it by viewing in `packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:32`

Body :

```
 `{"query":"query availableStoresConfigData {\n    availableStores {\n        code\n        id\n        store_name\n        default_display_currency_code\n    }\n}\n"}`
```

Response should be like this:

```js
{
    "data": {
        "availableStores": [
            {
                "code": "default",
                "id": 1,
                "store_name": "Default Store View",
                "default_display_currency_code": "USD"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not supported on version **2.3** [available-stores](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/available-stores.html)

Comment: it's not supported on 2.4 neither.